# Communication not possible with HyperV Virtual Maschine

Tags: webserver, windows-8, ubuntu-12.04, hyper-v

I started to work with hyper-v today. I setup an linux System in it. I now tried to also create a new internal network, because from monday on i don't have an network available but have to do some stuff on it. In the ubuntu server I also added all the hyper-v moduls into the kernel. As soon as I login in via ssh (I have a local connection via cable and an dhcp server in the network

```
System load:  0.13              Processes:           97
Usage of /:   21.6% of 7.47GB   Users logged in:     1
Memory usage: 28%               IP address for eth0: 192.168.0.14
Swap usage:   0%                IP address for eth1: 192.168.50.100
```

lsmod display's this:

```
Module                  Size  Used by
vesafb                 13516  1
joydev                 17393  0
hid_hyperv             12996  0
hid                    77367  1 hid_hyperv
psmouse                72846  0
serio_raw              13027  0
mac_hid                13077  0
i2c_piix4              13093  0
lp                     17455  0
parport                40930  1 lp
hv_netvsc              22462  0
hv_storvsc             17595  2
hv_utils               13284  0
floppy                 60310  0
hv_vmbus               29339  4 hid_hyperv,hv_netvsc,hv_storvsc,hv_utils
```

As you can see all moduls are loaded. On windows I gave the internal adapater the ip address 192.168.50.1 with the subnet mask 255.255.0.0

The network devices in the virtual maschine where identified as eth0 (external network) and eth1(as internal network)
eth0 works, because I can download packages from repository, so the interfaces work.

On the Linux System it is configurated to user the ip address 192.168.50.100 with the same subnet mask as above.

I can't connect the host with virtual maschine.
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Not exactly a programming related question.

Comment: I thought that you could also post other questions here?????
And the Virtualmaschine is thought to be a webserver. The OS is debian and the host is windows 8. So I set all of the tags correct.  So where was I mistaking?